# Symfony 5 hanndle access for external tools (knpsnappy)

Tags: symfony, security, symfony5, symfony-security, symfony-guard

In a Symfony 5.x project I use knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle.

Having private data-folders for different users results in generating PDF-documents that require images from folders which are not publicly accessable.

When trying to generate a PDF-document with an image in such a folder knpsnappy runs into a 60 sec timeout. The Symfony log says

```
Guard authenticator does not support the request.
```

I assume something regarding the "external" tool knpsnappy calling from outside the application but from the same server but does not triggering any security definition I defined.
I am unsure on how to allow knpsnappy to access a specific route.
Maybe someone can lead me into the right direction...?

Comment: This can be solved by adding a public route that returns the images. You could use uuids to make it near impossible for attackers to guess the image urls. If that's not save enough you could add a restriction for the route to be only accessable if the ip is your servers.

Comment: @Vyctorya Thanks. That sounds great. Could you give me a hint on how to define a security rule that makes a route completely pulbic? Not having a security rule for a route at all gives me the same message as defining a rule that gives access to IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY -> that would be "Guard authenticator does not support the request." as mentioned in my post. Any hints there?

Comment: @Vyctorya Maybe I can clarify that: Adding "{ path: ^/[my_path], ip: [my_server_ip] }" having ip set to the one the reqzest comes from doesn't help. It seems not to handle the request. Do I have to define a GuardAuthenticator myself to be able to catch this request and have it acceppted? I don't see why this should be required as the mentioned access rule should catch it. Shouldn't it?

Comment: You shouldn't need a custom authenticator. The order of the routes is important too. Maybe there is a more general route before? Also it should be 'ips' instead of 'ip' https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/access_control.html#matching-access-control-by-ip

Comment: Just googled the error and found this https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/24252 Maybe you need to return null in getCredentials if it's the image url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was misslead.
The cause of the problem wasn't access rights but the way the img-pathes were defined.
knp snappy wont be able to render images with URL-routes.
I switched the pathes to be absolut server pathes and now it works.
Found the solution here:
[KnpSnappyBundle and Symfony 3.4 : images and/or css cause timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50160083/knpsnappybundle-and-symfony-3-4-images-and-or-css-cause-timeout)